# printing a value of an array of strings in c

Tags: c, string, variable-assignment, cstring

So I've declared my strings as such
keys[25][50]; values[25][50];

I have a previous string that I'm splitting on whitespaces and then storing the values into either the key/value arrays respectively. The problem comes I suppose when I want to assign a string to a position in the array and then print out that value via printf(); It's always null. Am I doing anything wrong with the assignment of the string or print?

```
strcpy(buff, buf);
bufcopy = strtok(buff, " ");
if (strcmp(job, "PUT") == 0) {
    //keys[i] = bufcopy;
    strcpy(keys[i], bufcopy);
    printf("server received: %s", keys[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: What would `printf("bufcopy: %s", bufcopy);` show?

Comment: it shows the correct string. For some reason copying the string causes it to be null or some other value..

Comment: Post ***real*** code. You're saying it shows the "correct string" in *this **exact*** code ? As in: `printf("bufcopy: %s", bufcopy);` right above `printf("server received: %s", keys[i]);` ?? Post a working complete sample that exhibits your behavior. Assuming the declarations (which are not in the code and not *typed* in the question) are correct, then the only other logical thing would be `buff` is declared a pointer rather than a buffer, and again, without *real* code I can't conclude that either.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems you're trying to read in a Input like:

```
PUT key value
```

from command line and save these key/value pairs in your Arrays

```
char keys[25][50];
char values[25][50];
```

If that's what you trying to accomplish:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
  int i = 0;
  char keys[25][50];
  char values[25][50];
  char buf[256], *bufcopy;
  do{
    fgets(buf, 255, stdin);
    bufcopy = strtok(buf, " ");
    if (strcmp(bufcopy, "PUT") == 0) {
      bufcopy = strtok(NULL, " ");
      strcpy(keys[i], bufcopy);
      bufcopy = strtok(NULL, " ");
      strcpy(values[i], bufcopy);
      printf("server received pair %d - Key: %s\tValue: %s\n", i, keys[i], values[i]);
      i++;
    }
  }while(i<25);
  return 0;
}
```

This will read in inputs until you reached the end of your key/value array and save them into your arrays. You have to make successive calls to strtok() to split at every space and get a pointer to the next word (until next whitespace). For more informations about how it works, have a look at the reference of [strtok()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/).